# How to list files recursively with complete path, size, last accessed date and last modified date?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

It can be using find, ls or stat

```
find /opt/sas/data/vaa_oadm/sasdata -type f -name '*.sas7bdat'
```

Expected output:

```
/path/of/file/file1.sas7bdat 10GB 10Jan2020 01Jan2019
/path/of/file/on/server/file2.sas7bdat 10MB 15Jan2020 08Dec2019
```

Comment: What version of `find` are you using? Post the output of `find --version`

Comment: Try: `find /opt/sas/data/vaa_oadm/sasdata -type f -name '*.sas7bdat' -ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
find /opt/sas/data/vaa_oadm/sasdata -type f -name '*.sas7bdat' -printf "%p %kKB %Ad%Ab%AY %Td%Tb%TY\n"
```

Size is in K-bytes

Answer (score 1):

You can forward the files which are found by `find` by using `-exec` to any other prog.

So maybe you can try something like:

```
find /opt/sas/data/vaa_oadm/sasdata -type f -name '*.sas7bdat' -exec ls -lsa {} \;
```

the `{}` will be replaced by the found file name.

In addition find supports `-printf` which allows with a  lot of format variables to output a lot of formats for file meta information like size,mtime and so on. For detailed information take a look on [man page for find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)